# Allow numbers and Hyphen only using JavaScript without Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am trying to build a Nic validator without using Regular Expression(regex).

//Nic validation
// Expected output format 12345-1234567-1

Here is my code sample. What I am unable to figure out is how do I validate numbers and hyphens only?

```
let nicVal= myForm.nic.value;
let hyph ='-';


if(nicVal.length===0){
    console.log("Please enter the cnic");
}
else if(nicVal[5]===hyph && nicVal[5]===hyph )
{
console.log("Valid");
}
else{
    console.log("invalid");
}
```

Comment: Do hyphens and numbers only mean a fixed number of hyphens ?

Comment: Yes. It should be like 5 digits and then hyphen and then 7 digits and then hyphen and then 1 digit. The digits can be from(0-9).

Comment: Do you want these hyphens to be inserted as the user types?

Comment: Yes. The user will type these numbers as input and the validator should check first if there are 2 hyphens on the index 5 and 13.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much simpler using regular expressions, but as you ask for an alternative without a regex, try:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button')
let input = document.querySelector('input')

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let value = input.value
  let numbers = [Number(value.substr(0, 5)), Number(value.substr(6, 7)), Number(value.substr(14, 1))]
  numbers = numbers.map(value => {if(isNaN(value)) return 'NaN'; else return value})
  let hifens = [value.indexOf('-'), value.lastIndexOf('-')]
  if(numbers.indexOf('NaN') == -1 && hifens[0] == 5 && hifens[1] == 13) {
    console.log('Valid!')
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid!')
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="type..." maxlength="15" value="12345-1234567-1">
<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but there is still a bug in it. It is showing "Valid" for the alphabets as well and it is only checking hyphens and 15 characters.

Comment: Give an example of what you wrote

Comment: Understand. Fixed the problem, now it checks whether it's numbers or letters